# How to construct a Year, Month, Day - mm rain muliple PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

The following is an excerpt from a program which documents the rainy days by date in a month of a particular year.

```
function get_rain_detail ($year) {

// Cycle through the month and possible days 
for ($mnt = 0 ; $mnt < 12 ; $mnt++ ) {
    for ( $day = 0 ; $day < 31 ; $day++ ) {
        if ($maxdays[$mnt] < $day + 1 ) {
        } else {
            if ( $raw[$mnt][0][$day][$rawlb['rain']] == "" ) {
                $put = "---";
            } else {
                $put = sprintf("%01.1f", $raw[$mnt][0][$day][$rawlb['rain']]);
                $rainmonth[$mnt][0] = $rainmonth[$mnt][0] + $put;
                if ($put > 0.0) {
                    $rainmonth[$mnt][1] = $rainmonth[$mnt][1] + 1;
                }
                $data_rdays = sprintf("%01.1f", $put);
                $month=substr( $mnthname[$mnt], 0, 3 );     
                $days =$day+'1';
            }   
            $datay[] = "[$year,$month,$days,$data_rdays]";
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting array is `Array ( [0] => [2013,Jan,1,7.0] [1] => [2013,Jan,2,0.2] [2] => [2013,Jan,3,0.0] [3] => [2013,Jan,4,0.0]` etc.
I need to be able to extract all days of e.g. the month of Jan of e.g. the year ‘2013’. For this purpose I probably need to construct a multidimensional array from the $year, $month and $day loop, each day. Here is where I’m stuck and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably initially write values in array `$datay[]`, but making it associative. In that case you could just get all the data you need in the loop. Your new array could look like:

```
$datay[] = array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'days' => $days, 'data_rdays' => $data_rdays);
```

And then:

```
foreach($datay as $value) {
    if($value['year'] == 2013 && $value['month'] == 'Jan') {
        //do some stuff here...
    }
}
```

Simplest solution for me.